# Delete a Selected row in SQlite3

Tags: sql, sqlite

So I'm looking to delete a specific row. I have multiple rows with the same Email and I wanted to select a specific row depending on its order.

To get the specific row I ended up with this query:

```
select 
  * 
from (
  select 
    * 
  from 
    ExerciseData 
  where 
    Email='hej@hej.com' 
  order by 
    id desc 
  limit 2
) 
limit 1
```

How would I delete the row from this query?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Delete all but the first?

Comment: delete the first row out of all rows in descending order

Comment: So, based on the selected email, you want to keep the row with the highest id?

Comment: keep all the rows except for the first one in the descending order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get the primary key of that row, and use it to match the same row:

```
DELETE FROM ExerciseData
WHERE ID = (SELECT ID
            FROM ExerciseData
            WHERE Email = 'hej@hej.com'
            ORDER BY ID DESC
            LIMIT 1);
```